# Unix System Command Exit Code

Tags: linux, bash, unix, system

I'm trying to use the Unix System command to kick off a script and I receive the following error message.

**sh: location/script.ksh: No such file or directory**

The error message is expected but what I cant figure out is how to make the system command exit with a failure.

The code I'm using is below, would anyone happen to know where im going wrong or what I am missing?

```
elif [ ${VAR} -gt 0 ]; then

**grep for string** |
awk -v job_text="${VAR2}" \
-v job_seq_no=0 \
'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; \
{ command_pos=index($1,job_text)+length(job_text) } ;\
                      { job_seq_no++ } ; \
                      { system (substr($1,command_pos,length($1)-command_pos))}'
```

Im not much of a scripter so sorry if this is a dumb question or not possible.

Thanks in advance!

Cameron

Comment: This is nowhere near enough information for anyone to help.  What `system` command?  There's no `system` command in the code you posted.  `location/script.ksh`?!?!  Where does that come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to exit the script?  You need to note the return value of system within awk, and then report that to the shell as the exit status of awk.  Just store the value returned by system in a variable, and pass that variable as an argument to exit.  For a simple example, consider:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

if echo "$1" | awk '{r=system $0} END {exit r}'; then
        echo awk succeeded
else
        echo awk failed >&2
        exit 1
fi

$ ./a.sh false
awk failed
$ ./a.sh true
awk succeeded
```

If you just want to exit awk, you could use

```
awk '{r=system (...); if (r!=0){exit r}}'
```

Comment: Thank you very much William, using this "{r=system (...); if (r!=0){exit r}}" the system now recognises the exit code should be 127 and fails accordingly. Appreciate you taking the time to respond!